# How to convert a numeric vector to a string in R?

Tags: r

I need to convert a numeric vector to a string, for example,

```
c(1,0,3,4,5)
```

into

```
"10345"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with function `paste()` and argument `collapse=""`.

```
x<-c(1,0,3,4,5)
paste(x,collapse="")
[1] "10345"
```

Comment: Strictly speaking `paste0(x, collapse="")` is said to be more efficient, although hardly matters for a vector this size.

Answer (score 1):

`do.call(paste0,as.list(x))`

The good thing about this method is that it would work with any other function, not only paste().

Comment: Yes, I missed that by mistake. Thanks!